# I have a table where where each project_id generates multiple rows

Tags: oracle, case

My table below shows the rows and columns where the column data is filtered using a CASE syntax to differentiate capital from expense. The problem is I am getting multiple rows per project_ID.
I need one row per project_ID:
[image]

I need the output to be:

[image]
Here is my Oracle SQl (which includes many other columns not shown above):

```
SELECT
    pi.project_id,
    pi.project_projectnumber, 
    pi.project_projectname, 
    cst.cost1,

    CASE WHEN bi.code = '01-00-000' THEN  cst.ubr_ROM_Approved
         ELSE NULL
    END AS CAPITAL_ROM,  

    CASE WHEN bi.code = '02-00-000' 
         THEN cst.ubr_ROM_Approved
         ELSE NULL
    END AS EXPENSE_ROM,  

    CASE WHEN bi.code = '01-00-000' 
         THEN cst.ubacf_CD_Approved
         ELSE NULL
    END AS CAPITAL_ADJ_CD,  

    CASE WHEN bi.code = '01-00-000' 
         THEN cst.ubacf_SD_Approved
         ELSE NULL
    END AS CAPITAL_ADJ_SD,  

    CASE WHEN bi.code = '01-00-000' 
         THEN cst.ubacf_DD_Approved
         ELSE NULL
    END AS CAPITAL_ADJ_DD,  

    CASE WHEN bi.code = '01-00-000' 
         THEN cst.ubacf_Budget_Approved
         ELSE NULL
    END AS CAPITAL_ADJ_Budget,  

    CASE WHEN bi.code = '02-00-000' 
         THEN cst.ubacf_CD_Approved
         ELSE NULL
    END AS EXPENSE_ADJ_CD,  

    CASE WHEN bi.code = '02-00-000' 
         THEN cst.ubacf_SD_Approved
         ELSE NULL
    END AS EXPENSE_ADJ_SD,  

    CASE WHEN bi.code = '02-00-000' 
         THEN cst.ubacf_DD_Approved
         ELSE NULL
    END AS EXPENSE_ADJ_DD,  

    CASE WHEN bi.code = '02-00-000' 
         THEN cst.ubacf_Budget_Approved
         ELSE NULL
    END AS EXPENSE_ADJ_Budget


FROM turnerb_upi_view pi
INNER JOIN turnerb_sys_project_info_view pv ON (pv.pid = pi.project_id)
INNER JOIN turnerb_us_p1_view prj ON (prj.pid = pi.project_id)
INNER JOIN turnerb_budget_summary_viewb cst ON (cst.projectid = pi.project_id)
INNER JOIN turnerb_ubr_view rom ON (rom.project_id = pi.project_id)
INNER JOIN turnerb_ubacf_view badj ON (badj.project_id = pi.project_id)
INNER JOIN turnerb_budgetitem bi ON (bi.budgetid = cst.budgetid)

WHERE pi.project_status = '1' 
AND rom.status ='ROM_Approved' 
AND (badj.status = 'SD_Approved' 
     OR badj.status = 'CD_Approved' 
     OR badj.status = 'DD_Approved' 
     OR badj.status = 'Budget_Approved')

GROUP BY 
    pi.project_id,
    pi.project_projectnumber, 
    pi.project_projectname, 
    bi.code,
    cst.cost1,
    cst.ubr_ROM_Approved,
    cst.ubacf_CD_Approved,
    cst.ubacf_SD_Approved,
    cst.ubacf_DD_Approved,
    cst.ubacf_Budget_Approved

ORDER BY project_projectnumber;
```

Comment: ELSE NULL is default so you can skip that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

to obtain the output you need, all that is necessary is

```
SELECT project_id, SUM(capital_rom), SUM (expense_rom), ...
   ...
   GROUP BY project_id
```

I do not see the connex between your desired output and your statement ...

Comment: I did that and now I am getting one row per project_id as expected, however, the Capital_ROM and Expense_ROM columns are giving the same values.... Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

The columns or expressions that you want to be unique in your output must be included in `GROUP BY`.  The columns that need to be aggregated, or the columns that form expressions to be aggregated, must **not** be in `GROUP BY`.

Your query contains much more columns than the simplified example in your snapshots, and you are not elaborating on which ones are supposed to be unique in the resulting set.  Therefore I am going to be guessing here.  It seems to me the `GROUP BY` terms should be the first four columns in your `SELECT` clause:

```
pi.project_id,
pi.project_projectnumber, 
pi.project_projectname, 
cst.cost1,
```

You should keep those in `GROUP BY` and remove all the others.  As for the `SELECT` clause, all the `CASE` expressions need to be encased in `SUM`s.  Here are all the changes that you need to apply to your query:

```
SELECT
    pi.project_id,
    pi.project_projectnumber, 
    pi.project_projectname, 
    cst.cost1,

    SUM(  /* same expression, but aggregated */
        CASE WHEN bi.code = '01-00-000' THEN  cst.ubr_ROM_Approved
             ELSE NULL
        END
    ) AS CAPITAL_ROM,  

    SUM(  /* same expression, but aggregated */
        CASE WHEN bi.code = '02-00-000' 
             THEN cst.ubr_ROM_Approved
             ELSE NULL
        END
    ) AS EXPENSE_ROM,  

    ... /* follow the above pattern for the rest of the columns */

FROM ... /* no changes here */

WHERE ... /* no changes here */

GROUP BY
    /* only these four need to be GROUP BY terms */
    pi.project_id,
    pi.project_projectnumber, 
    pi.project_projectname, 
    cst.cost1

ORDER BY project_projectnumber;
```